# Finding indexes of duplicates in an array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

Write a program that takes the user input as an integer array and displays the duplicate values in that array along with their index.

Rules:

You need to get the array size from the user first before taking in the array values
Your array size cannot be zero.
If there are no duplicates, your program needs to display that message.

This is my code, but the program stops when I fill up an array with the duplicate number. It doesn't let me fill up the array all the way. How to fix that?

```java
package arraysPractice;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class homeworkArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Please enter an array size: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        int[] choiceArray = new int[choice];

        System.out.println("Please enter your array values: ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= choice; i++) {
            choiceArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
            for (int j = i + 1; j < choiceArray.length; j++) {
                if ((choiceArray[i] == choiceArray[j]) && (i != j)) {
                    System.out.print("Duplicate Element : " + choiceArray[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(choiceArray));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @KevinO said in a comment, you most certainly have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

`for (int i = 0; i <= choice; i++);` should be `for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++)`

Try this, please.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an array size:(Press 'enter key' to submit the value) ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice = keyboard.nextInt();

        Integer[] choiceArray = new Integer[choice];

        System.out.println("Please enter your array digits:(Press 'enter key' to submit the digit) ");

        for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++)
            choiceArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(choiceArray);

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(list::get));

        final boolean[] foundDuplicates = {false};

        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if (v.size() > 1) {
                foundDuplicates[0] = true;
                System.out.println("digit: " + k + " | duplicate indexes: " + v);
            }
        });

        if (!foundDuplicates[0])
            System.out.println("No duplicate digits found!");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I could come up with, the second method might be able to improvise:

```
public class Util
{
    public static Set<Integer> findDuplicates(List<Integer> numbers)
    {
        Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
        return numbers.stream().filter(number -> !result.add(number)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public static Map<Integer, Integer> findDuplicatesWithIndices(List<Integer> numbers)
    {
        Map<Integer, Integer> result = new TreeMap<>();
        Set<Integer> duplicates = findDuplicates(numbers);

        int pos = 0;

        for (Integer number : numbers)
        {
            if (duplicates.contains(number))
            {
                result.put(number, pos);
            }

            pos++;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 7, 7, 9, 4, 1, 2, 0));
        Map<Integer, Integer> duplicatesWithIndices = findDuplicatesWithIndices(numbers);
        duplicatesWithIndices.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Value " + k + " duplicates at Index " + v));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Value 3 duplicates at Index 7
Value 4 duplicates at Index 11
Value 7 duplicates at Index 9
Value 9 duplicates at Index 10
```

Now, the first method - findDuplicates is really fast in what it does but can't really come up with the indices. I used a map in the traditional way to generate the indices as you said you need it.

In the main method where I have declared a List you can capture the values from the user and put it there. Then print as you like the output.

Answer (score 0):

It could be convenient to use Stream API to build a map of values to the indexes, then filter by the size of the index list and display duplicates:

```java
public static Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> getDuplicates(int ... data) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> duplicates = IntStream.range(0, data.length)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> data[i], LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toSet()));
    duplicates.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getValue().size() < 2);

    return duplicates;
}
```

Test:

```java
getDuplicates(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2)
    .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("Duplicate %d at %s%n", k, v));
```

Output

```
Duplicate 1 at [0, 3, 4]
Duplicate 2 at [1, 9]
Duplicate 3 at [2, 5, 8]
```

Or the output may be improved to show the duplicates in the order they have appeared in the input:

```java
getDuplicates(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2)
.entrySet().stream()
.flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(ix -> Arrays.asList(e.getKey(), ix)))
.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr.get(1)))
.forEach(arr -> System.out.printf("Duplicate %d at %s%n", arr.get(0), arr.get(1)));
```

Output

```
Duplicate 1 at 0
Duplicate 2 at 1
Duplicate 3 at 2
Duplicate 1 at 3
Duplicate 1 at 4
Duplicate 3 at 5
Duplicate 3 at 8
Duplicate 2 at 9
```

---

Another simpler approach without using streams:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> dups = new HashMap<>();
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2};
int i = 0;
for (int x : arr) {
    dups.computeIfAbsent(x, (key) -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i++);
    if (dups.get(x).size() > 1) {
        List<Integer> ix = dups.get(x);
        if (ix.size() == 2) {
            System.out.printf("Duplicate %d at %s%n", x, ix.get(0));
        }
        System.out.printf("Duplicate %d at %s%n", x, ix.get(ix.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

Output (not sorted by index)

```
Duplicate 1 at 0
Duplicate 1 at 3
Duplicate 3 at 2
Duplicate 3 at 4
Duplicate 1 at 5
Duplicate 3 at 6
Duplicate 3 at 9
Duplicate 2 at 1
Duplicate 2 at 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect a map of duplicates from this list as follows:

```java
List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "d", "b", "c", "a");
```

```java
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = IntStream
        .range(0, list.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // key - element of the list
                list::get,
                // value - list indices of these elements
                i -> new ArrayList<>(List.of(i)),
                // merge two lists
                (l1, l2) -> {
                    l1.addAll(l2);
                    return l1;
                },
                // map with encounter order of elements
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

```java
// output
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
//a=[0, 5]
//b=[1, 3]
//d=[2]
//c=[4]
```